# Can I hook up drone battery directly to transmitter?

Tags: voltage, power, batteries

I have a hs150 drone that doesn't come with a camera. I am trying to make my DIY FPV camera. The specs for my drone battery are this:

- Capacity: 600 mAh
- Voltage: 3.7 V
- Battery Type: LiPo
- Energy 2.22 Wh
- Net Weight 19.0 g

I am thinking about buying this transmitter:

- Brand name: Eachine
- Item name: ATX03S Mini FPV Transmitter
- Output power: 25mW/50mW/100mW/200mW adjustable
- Input voltage: 3.3V-5V
- 5V camera supply, 245mA(MAX)-----25mW@4.2V (Typical)
- 5V camera supply, 310mA(MAX)-----50mW@4.2V (Typical)
- 5V camera supply, 390mA(MAX)-----100mW@4.2V (Typical)
- 5V camera supply, 517mA(MAX)-----200mW@4.2V(Typical)
- Video format: NTSC/PAL
- Antenna dimensions: 55mm X 2mm diameter
- Antenna: IPEX
- Frequency: 5.8GHz 5 bands 40 channels
- Size: 1916mm(LW)
- Weight: 2.959

I checked the voltage on my drone. Fully charged, it has a voltage of ~4.2 volts. The lowest voltage the drone flies at is about 3.6 volts. So I think this is within the requirements of the transmitter's input voltage. However I'm confused about the input voltage range since the transmitter has a 5V camera supply.

- Wouldn't this require the input voltage to be at least 5 volts?
- I'm also worried about the power draw on the drone battery and
  whether it will significantly effect flight time (7 min fully
  charged).

Comment: Questions about the usage of consumer products are off topic.  For a single cell aircraft you might as well get a little fpv cam with built in tx designed for single cell "tinywhoop" use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> worried about the power draw on the drone battery and whether
>   it will significantly effect flight time (7 min fully charged).

Assuming the battery has 600mAh usable capacity and is 90% drained in 7 minutes, the average current draw should be 0.6*(60/7)*0.9 = ~4.6 Amps. At 100mV rf output the transmitter draws a maximum of 390mA, which would reduce the flight time by a maximum of 0.39/4.6 = 8.5%.

This does not take into account the camera's current draw, which I am presuming is insignificant. It also doesn't take into account the extra power required to fly with the added weight of the camera and transmitter.

> I checked the voltage on my drone. Fully charged, it has a voltage of
>   ~4.2 volts. The lowest voltage the drone flies at is about 3.6 volts.
>   So I think this is within the requirements of the transmitter's input
>   voltage.

Yes, it should work - provided that the transmitter can handle a varying input voltage with a lot of ripple on it. Hopefully the 5V camera power output is well regulated (if not you may get interference lines on the image due to motor noise getting into the camera circuit).

> the transmitter has a 5V camera supply. Wouldn't this require the
>   input voltage to be at least 5 volts?

The only way the spec makes sense is if the transmitter has an internal voltage booster which converts 3.3-5V to 5V. The rf power output is specified @4.2V, which *suggests* that the transmitter is designed to be powered directly from a 3.7V (nominal) Lithium-ion battery.

Comment: Thank you. I am curious about your calculation `0.6(60/7)*0.9 = ~4.6 Amps`. Why don't you divide 7/60?

Comment: multiplying by 60/7 is the same as dividing by 7/60. I will edit the equation to make the multiplication more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Things do exist that allow us to step up voltage when we need to. That transmitter contains a boost converter that can step up voltage to 5V.

It's a lot simpler to step down voltage so we go that route if we can, but in some cases it doesn't make sense to do so.  This scenario is one of them because the motors are much higher power than the camera, and it makes sense to run such a small drone off one cell so the motors take priority in the battery selection. Therefore, we need a boost converter to provide the voltage necessary for the camera.

Comment: ok, but if I put the transmitter in parallel with the drone's circuit will it work?

Comment: @st4rgut Did you not understand the second sentence in my answer? It's in direct response to the only question you asked in your post.

Comment: Yes I understand that part. So does that mean I can hook up the transmitter directly to battery? By "take priority" do you mean that hooking transmitter in parallel will result in 0 current draw to the transmitter?  Why would I need to step down voltage if battery voltage is within the transmitter's input voltage range? I thought current draw depends on the load. Sorry my understanding is limited.

Comment: When I say "take priority" I just mean the priorities of the people who design drones and that transmitter. They could have designed the drone motors to take 2S batteries so that you could power the 5V camera with a simpler step-down regulator, but that doesn't make sense since the drone motors are higher power devices than the 5V camera.

Comment: @st4rgut I'm saying all this because of your comment "I'm confused about the input voltage range since the transmitter has a 5V camera supply. Wouldn't this require the input voltage to be at least 5 volts?" as if was impossible for the transmitter to produce 5V from a 3.6V supply. It's not a straight wire from the input wire of the transmitter to the output wire for the camera supply. There's a boost converter sitting in between. Now that you know that, do YOU think you can connect the transmitter directly to the battery or not? Because I already answered your question.

Comment: yes, just to clarify that was one of my questions as I mentioned in the unedited version of my post. My main questions was whether I could wire  the battery to power the transmitter's circuit. It helps knowing there's a boost converter. Thanks